# Inheritance depending on calculated attribute

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, design-patterns

I am curently working on a small project (C#) where I have data to analyse.
To do so, I pass the data into the constructor of a class.

The class makes a first analysis on the data, and a certain value is determined using the data. Using this value I can say that this data is of Type B, C, D, ... and the analysis would continue in another class corresponding to the data type.

This would be it's class diagram representation :

[image]

So the "Data" Class should abstract but not really ? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I did some reasearch about the factory design pattern, but I think this is not really what I am trying to achieve. Is there maybe an other design pattern that does what I want to do?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the code that you currently have (or some representation of it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the base class to determine which child class to create based on the data passed into the constructor. If so, you can't do it that way - a class cannot change itself to be a different/derived type when being constructed.

I assume that all the data types have some common properties and so you decided to put those common properties in a base class. I also assume you don't want each data type child class to have redundant code setting those common properties in the base class. You accomplish that by having the child class call a method in the base class, passing the data. You can do this in the constructors if you wish. For example:

```
class BaseData
{
    BaseData(Dictionary<string,string> data)
    {
        this.CommonProp1 = data["CommonProp1"];
        this.CommonProp2 = data["CommonProp2"];
    }

    public string CommonProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp2 { get; set; }
}

class DataTypeA : BaseData
{
    DataTypeA(Dictionary<string,string> data)
        : base(data) // <-- magic here
    {
        this.TypeA_Prop1 = data["TypeA_Prop1"];
        this.TypeA_Prop2 = data["TypeA_Prop2"];
    }

    public string TypeA_Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string TypeA_Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I believe the factory pattern actually is what you want since you want to create an instance of a class in which the type is determined at run time. This is where you encapsulate the code that determines which type of child class to create. Something like:

```
class DataFactory
{
    public static BaseData BuildDataClass(byte[] serializedData)
    {
        Dictionary<string,string> data = ParseData(serializedData);
        switch (data["DataType"])
        {
            case "TypeA":
                return new DataTypeA(data);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string,string> ParseData(byte[] serializedData)
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // bla bla

        return data;
    }
}
```